# Why is this convolution true?

Tags: terminology, summation, convolution, correlation

I am a little puzzled by how the following summation has been written as a convolution, with one of the inputs *reversed* in time. Consider the following sum on the LHS, and the convolution on the RHS. I am trying to ascertain why they are equal.

$$
\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} h[i-l] \ x[i] = h[-l] * x[l]
$$

How/Why was the $h[-l]$ ascertained here? I have read and re-read the wiki on convolution and other links, but I cannot seem to figure out how you get it. Can someone please explain to me step by step what is going on here? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Case1: I am told to assume $g[n] = h[-n]$. This seems to work for this case, but not for another case. In this case, I get:

$$
\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} h[i-l] \ x[i] = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} g[-(i-l)] \ x[i] = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} g[l-i] \ x[i] = g[l] * x[l] = h[-l]*x[l]
$$

This seems to work.

Case 2: However, if I try it on a different scenario, it does not work. Suppose we wanted to calculate the convolution sum of $h[k] * h^*[-k]$. The **right** answer is that:

$$
h[k] * h^*[-k] = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h[n] \ h*[n+k]
$$

But using this method, I would get:

$$
h[k] * h^*[-k] = h[k] * g^*[k] = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h[n] \ g^*[k-n] = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h[n] \ h^*[-(k-n)] = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h[n] \ h^*[n-k]
$$

...which is not the same as the right answer.

Comment: So here is where the ambiguous notation comes in: for part  2 you have an expression for $ (h \ast h^\ast)[-k]$ whereas it doesn't match $(h \ast h^\ast_r)[k]$

Comment: @Evan Not getting it. Can you please expand this point in your answer. I have to also say, that in my 4 years undergrad in engineering, we were never taught this notation you are using. Not saying its bad, just that I am not sure how you are using this notation, and how/why it matters. I do not see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Evan Also related: How do you determine the index in this notation? Why is $h[k]*h^*[-k]$ really $(h * h^*)[-k]$ and not $(h * h^*)[k]$ for instance? Perhaps if I learn this new notation those problems will vanish. Right now I do not get it.

Comment: That was my point to you actually. My notation is not ambiguous. I will refine my answer to show you in a bit, but I think there is value in treating convolution as taking two sequences to a third sequence and the notation should reflect that. When you reverse a sequence, which one is being reversed, the convolution or an individual sequence before convolution?

Comment: @Evan I dont disagree. All I am saying is that we dont encounter this notation you are referring to in engineering, so when you simple say "look at notation" I do not know what to do. By all means please elucidate this step by step, since it would seem to make for a richer understanding on my part in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: ok see edit now, hope it helps

Comment: @Evan I posted to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, let $g$ be $h$ reversed, and rewrite as $\sum g[l-i] x[i]$, and that already shows you that your sum is $(g \ast x)[l]$.  The quick memory trick is that in the sum above, if you sum the indices, $l-i+i = l$ tells you which entry of the convolution is being computed.

Note $g[x] = h[-x]$.

So I feel the notation is slightly confusing in what you wrote. I would have written
that $(g \ast x)[l] = \sum_i g[l-i]x[i] = \sum_i h[i-l]x[i]$, just so the indices don't get confusing.

---

In your linked document, let us translate the notation to something more reasonable:

- Fourth line (first convolution appearance):  $(h \ast R_{xx})[m+l]$.
- Fifth line: $ (h^\ast_r \ast ( h \ast R_{xx} ))[m] $ where $h^\ast_r$ is the reversed sequence of $h^\ast$.

Why not just stop here? Now by associativity and commutativity of convolutions, you can jump to the bottom already... And again, that notation does leave something to complain about.

---

Notation:

$(g\ast h)[k] = \sum_i g[i] h[k-i]$

So your sum
$\sum h[n] h^\ast[-k-n] = (h\ast h^\ast)[-k]$. (sum the indices to get which index of the convolution you solve for)

on the other hand
$\sum h[n] h^\ast[-(k-n)] = (h\ast h^\ast[-(\cdot)])[k]$

Hope this clarifies somewhat what I am getting at.

Comment: Let me just put the whole problem on here then. I am trying to figure out how he got the last line [here](http://d.pr/i/kIxJ). How did he get that $h[-m]$ in the last line? I get everything else before that.

Comment: Evan, thanks for the update. I am sorry but I still do not see how - exactly - we get the $h[-m]$ from. I tried working out by hand when you said let $g$ be $h$ reversed. However when you say let that happen, where are you saying for this to happen? INSIDE the convolution summation? Before that, working backwards? Sorry I am truly confused and at this point flustered.

Comment: If $g[\tau] = h[-\tau]$, then you are saying that $g[l-i] = h[i-l]$ necessarily? And so, we just do this change inside the convolution summation? (Line 4 in the doc)

Comment: Evan, I checked this again this morning and I do not think this is correct. The math does not seem to check out.

Comment: Evan, I edited my post showing where this method appears to break down.

Comment: Sigh, I am afraid that does not clarify it for me. It doesnt make sense. 1) $(h∗h∗)[−k]$ - what does the $-k$ go to? The first vector or the second? How would you know? 2) You say sum the indicies, but in the last example this sum becomes $2n - k$...yet you have a $k$ as the index somehow.. 0_o. 3) I am still unclear as to how this helps Case-2 in my edit.

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond Chat is acting funny, will delete some previous comments instead and put here:  Can you tell me what your definition of $h[j] \ast g[k]$ is?

Comment: I have never encountered a convolution in that form, so I do not know.

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond  That's why I don't like that notation. but in your post you are telling me to evaluate $h[k] \ast h^\ast [-k]$. What is that defined to be equal to?

Comment: Ah ok, right so what I have here is [this here](http://d.pr/i/2Amr)

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond  Hmm... wait then you are asking about what is going on when you plug in $g^\ast[k] = h^\ast[-k]$ into the formula right? But that definition is not compatible with the reversal procedure. What I am saying, is that the given definition of $h[k]\ast h^\ast[-k]$ in the link is equal to $(h \ast h^\ast)[-k]$ of my notation. So it wouldn't make sense to replace $h^\ast[k]$ by $g^\ast[-k]$, because doing so would get you the formula of a different convolution, as you found out in your post. So I want to emphasize why that notation is awful,awful.

Comment: Why isn't there a link to the chat automatically? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10426/discussion-between-thegrapebeyond-and-evan    Also, wanted to say that for (2), in the last example I summed the indices if I pretended that $h$ and reversed $h^\ast$ were my sequences. So $n$ from $h$ and $k-n$ from $h^\ast(-(\cdot))$.

Answer (score 0):

> what is going on here?

An error, or an arguably bad notation. Actually, neither the more usual $h[n] * x[n]$ is very correct.

The convolution of the signals $x[n]$ and $h[n]$ is another signal $g[n] = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} h[i-n] \ x[i]$; this is totally correct. Now, if we denote this operation by $x[n] * h[n]$, we shoud write $g[n] = x[n] * h[n]$, and we could conclude that, say, $g[8] = x[8] * h[8]$... which, of course is nonsense. The correct form should be $(h * x)[n]$, as the Wikipedia article uses - but one often writes $x[n] * h[n]$ (abuse of notation) to mean that.

Comment: I am not sure it is bad notation. I am simply going off [this](http://d.pr/i/kIxJ), trying to figure out how he got the last line with the $h[-m]$. I get everything else before that.

Comment: Typo: don't you mean $h[n-i]$ rather than $h[i-n]$?